# Accessing a velocity template from different domain using jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I have an application which uses Apache Velocity deployed on the same server (because I am developing it locally but could be on another server in Prod). From my current application, I need to fetch a Velocity Template from that application and display that template in a Jquery Dialog box. 
I am able to make a cross domain ajax call

```
$.ajax({
         url         : '/ContextRootOfdifferentApplication/preview.do',
         data        : 'previewJson=' + JSON.stringify(dataForPreview),
         contentType : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
         crossDomain : true,
         type        : "POST",
         dataType    : 'html',
         success     : function(response){
             window.open(response);
           }
         });
```

In the debugger, I could see the response as a valid HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <div id="container" align="center">
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="width: 80%; height: 10px; background-color: #6698FF;"></div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="errormsg" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Preview Not Available!!!</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="width: 80%; height: 10px; background-color: #6698FF;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However as soon as I try to display this HTML page as a pop-up or in jQuery dialog, a 404 error appears

> HTTP Status 404 -
>   /currentApp/%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cdiv%20id=%22container%22%20align=%22center%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E %3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%3E %3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%22width:%2080%;%20height:%2010px;%20background-color:%20
>
> message
>   /currentApp/%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cdiv%20id=%22container%22%20align=%22center%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E %3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%3E %3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%22width:%2080%;%20height:%2010px;%20background-color:%20
>
> description The requested resource
>   (/currentApp/%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cdiv%20id=%22container%22%20align=%22center%22%3E%3Cdiv%3E %3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%3E %3C/div%3E%3Cdiv%20style=%22width:%2080%;%20height:%2010px;%20background-color:%20)
>   is not available.

Any idea what I am missing here which could be causing this error?

ps:**ContextRootOfdifferentApplication** The application to which i am making the ajax call.
**currentApp** : The application which i am making an Ajax call

Answer (score 1):

Okay finally I found the solution/mistake which I was doing.
When I was trying to open this as a popup window I was writing

```
window.open(response)
```

Since response was the html code fetched from the ajax call, it could not make a URL out of it and threw 404 error.

I was doing the same mistake while opening a jquery dialog with it.

Finally this line worked for me:

```
$('#response').html(response).dialog({modal:true});
```